# How to access script binding variable when Define a Class in groovy?

Tags: groovy

How to access the a in the Class A?

```
a = [1:2,2:3]

class A {
    def m() {
        println a
    }

}


new A().m()
```

This has error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Properties are defined in an object called `Binding`. Your class doesn't have the semantic of a closure : it access only properties defined in his own class or in the parent class.

Try this :

```
​a = [1:2,2:3] 

class A {
  def context

  def m() { println context.a     }  
}   

new A(context:binding).m()​
```